# Shiny: Making RHandsontable read only on click

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I want to make my rhandsontable read only on clicking the action button 'Freeze Forecast' and activate the table on clicking on 'Edit Forecast'. It should show me the Sum Output on clicking on 'Generate Forecast' button.

Please help to correct my existing code as per above conditions.

### UI.R

```
packages <- c( "shiny", "data.table", "devtools", "shinysky","googleVis","scales","rhandsontable" )
lapply( packages, require, character.only = TRUE )

jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}" #JS Code to refresh the App

did_recalc <- FALSE

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Scenario Planner Test App"),

    br(),br(),
  actionButton("recalc", "Generate Forecast"),
  actionButton("edit", "Edit Forecast"),
  actionButton("freeze", "Freeze Forecast"),br(),br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('table'),br(),br(),
  textOutput('restitle'),
  textOutput('result')

)
```

### Server.R

```
Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD="/usr/bin/zip")
packages <- c( "shiny", "data.table", "devtools", "shinysky","googleVis","scales","reshape2" )
lapply( packages, require, character.only = TRUE )

disableActionButton <- function(id,session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode1",
                            list(code= paste("$('#",id,"').prop('disabled',true)"
                                             ,sep="")))
}

enableActionButton <- function(id,session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode2",
                            list(code= paste("$('#",id,"').prop('disabled',false)"
                                             ,sep="")))
}


shiny::shinyServer( function(input,output,session)({
  values <- reactiveValues(data=as.data.frame(runif(2)))

  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data <- as.data.frame(runif(2))
  })

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$table))
     values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
  })


  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data)
    })

  observe({
    input$freeze
    print("freeze")
    ##if(!is.null(input$table))
    print("2freeze")
    rhandsontable(values$data)  %>%
    hot_table(readOnly = TRUE)
  })


  output$restitle <- renderText({ 
          "Sum Output"
     })

  output$result <- renderText({ 
    sum(values$data)
  })
}) 
)
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer below? It was a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by

- Adding a state variable to your reactive called `readonly`
- Adding two `observerEvent` routines to the `edit` and `freeze` action buttions to toggle `readonly`.
- Modifying your `output$table` command to use the reactive `readonly` variable.

It would have been easier, and not needed a lot of those elements if you had just used a checkbox to indicate that the table is editable, and then wired that variable to the `readOnly` parameter, but sometimes you need to do it this way, so I solved it like this.

The complete **server.R** code is here:

```
packages <- c("shiny","data.table","devtools","shinysky","googleVis","scales","reshape2")
lapply(packages,require,character.only = TRUE)

disableActionButton <- function(id,session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = "jsCode1",
                            list(code = paste("$('#",id,"').prop('disabled',true)"
                                             ,sep = "")))
}

enableActionButton <- function(id,session) {
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = "jsCode2",
                            list(code = paste("$('#",id,"').prop('disabled',false)"
                                             ,sep = "")))
}


shiny::shinyServer(function(input,output,session)({

  values <- reactiveValues(data = as.data.frame(runif(2)),readonly=FALSE)

  observe({
    input$recalc
    values$data <- as.data.frame(runif(2))
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$table))
      values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
  })


  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data,readOnly=values$readonly)
  })

  observeEvent(input$edit, {
   values$readonly <- FALSE
  })

  observeEvent(input$freeze,{
    values$readonly <- TRUE
  })


  output$restitle <- renderText({
    "Sum Output"
  })

  output$result <- renderText({
    sum(values$data)
  })
})
)
```

and it looks like this:

[image]